# How to rename all files names in folder based on another file name folder?

Tags: python

I have 1000+ files in 2 folders.
I want to rename all of them in 1st folder based on second folder file names?

my test script

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("/home/folder1"):
    os.rename(file, f"/home/folder2")
```

Comment: How you want to match files between folders?

Comment: in folders files quantity are same . so i just need to loop them and rename one by one

Comment: You don't care about previous name of files in 2nd folder?

Comment: exactly , just need new ones which i get from 1st folder

Comment: What about extensions?

Comment: yep forgot about them. all file names but not extensions. So all before .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

src = Path(r"/home/folder1")
dst = Path(r"/home/folder2")
for s, d in zip(src.iterdir(), dst.iterdir()):
    d.rename(d.with_stem(s.stem))
    # for python lower than 3.9 use next line
    # d.rename(d.with_name(s.with_suffix(d.suffix).name))
```

P.S. [`Path.with_stem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem) have been added in python 3.9, so I've added line with implementation for lower versions.

Comment: hey, i found error in it. After renaming info in files were randoming . not as 1 by 1 as original. How to fix that?

Comment: @alexuuu, sorry, I don't clearly understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `os.walk()` instead of `os.listdir()`.

`os.walk()` returns a generator object containing all subfolders, files and parent directories. So just specify the root folder and you are good.

```
import os

result = list(os.walk())

for parent, directories, files in result:
    if parent == "folder_name_1":
        for file in files:
            os.rename(parent + '/' + file, parent + '/' + "new_name_of_the_file")
```

This is a vague answer, you might want your renaming logic to be different based on your needs.